# Select join with all matches

Tags: sql

Table :

```
CREATE TABLE product_option
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  option_type character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  value character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  product_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT product_option_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id ),
  CONSTRAINT fk_product FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
      REFERENCES product (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

A user can search for products that have a list of options.
i.e. 
Find products that have these options :

```
BINDING_SIDE : BOTTOM
BINDING_SIDE : TOP
BINDING_TYPE : COIL_BINDING
```

The result should only return the products that have at least these three options. ( they can have more options )

Comment: Please paste your data as text, properly formatted, and show us the code you have so far

Comment: what code have you tried so far

Answer (score 1):

This won't work if you can have duplicate `option_type, value` combinations:

```
Select
    Product_id
From
    Product_Options
Where
    (Option_Type = 'BINDING_SIDE' and value = 'BOTTOM') Or
    (Option_Type = 'BINDING_SIDE' and value = 'TOP') Or
    (Option_Type = 'BINDING_TYPE' and value = 'BOTTOM') Or
Group By
    Product_id
Having
    Count(*) >= 3
```

Comment: I can have duplicate option_type - value combination, but not for one product.

Comment: This did work. And I guess if I put in the product id in the query I should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HAVING` and a conditional `SUM()` to get this:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING   SUM(CASE WHEN option_type = 'BINDING_SIDE' AND value = 'BOTTOM' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
     AND SUM(CASE WHEN option_type = 'BINDING_SIDE' AND value = 'TOP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
     AND SUM(CASE WHEN option_type = 'BINDING_TYPE' AND value = 'COIL_BINDING' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
```

Comment: That sql did not work :(

Comment: Works for me, what database are you using?

Comment: Hint: you're comparison is **SUM(xxx) > 1** :-)

Comment: Ha, whoops, updated to >= 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 SELECT product_id 
FROM product
group by product_id
having SUM(
    (case when (option_type = 'BINDING_SIDE' and value = 'BOTTOM') then 1 else 0 end)
   + (case when (option_type = 'BINDING_SIDE' and value = 'TOP') then 1 else 0 end)
   + (case when (option_type = 'BINDING_SIDE' and value = 'COIL_BINDING') then 1 else 0        end)
      ) >=3
```

Comment: That sql did not work... :(